# javafx scene builder controller unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx

Good day. I am a new learner of Java and I am currently stucking in performing a unit test for javafx scene builder controller.
I have an application class,

```
public class WebScraperApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ui.fxml"));
        VBox root = (VBox) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("WebScraper");
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

ui.fxml stores the GUI information and Controller class is the javafx scene builder controller,

```
public class Controller{
    @FXML
    //variable and constructor
    ...
    @FXML
    //function
    public int size(List<Object> x){
        return x.size();
    }
    ...
}
```

I have no idea to create a unit test to test the Controller class since I cannot create an object of it and implement the function inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX). It's a testing framework for Java FX